# Android Static Variables and Shared Preferences

Tags: android, variables, static, fragment

I am writing an android app and I retrieve a balance for the user from a webservice and the user is able to log in and out of my app.

When the app starts I check the shared preferences to see if the user is logged in or out.  On correct log in I update the shared pref boolean to true and set it to false when the user logs out.

I need to know the balance in several fragments and I need to remember it when I am navigating thru the fragments in my app.  When I return to the "My Account" fragment balance value is lost and I have to call my web service again to check it.

It the best way to use a string shared pref and update it any time the app starts or when there is a change in the balance. Or am I better to use a static variable in my main activity that can be referenced when the user navigates to the My Account fragment.

Is it possible to overuse shared preferences?

Comment: You can use SharedPreference, but if you want to store more data focus on Database. it is  good practice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a single value such as balance or username you should definitely use [SharedPrefereneces](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) and [OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener.html).

For structured data such as balance operations you should definitely use a database:

- **SQLite**
- **Realm** (noSQL)
- **StorIO** (SQLite wrapper)

or some **ORM**.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for the advice.  I am just going to write the balance in a shared pref as suggested.

Answer (score 1):

A simple and elegant solution is to use a very simple library TinyDB in android, which is nothing but an abstraction over the Shared Preferences.

You can initialise it in your activity's `onCreate()` method like this:

```
TinyDB tinydb = new TinyDB(this);
```

In fragment, just replace `this` with `getActivity`.

And then use it like this:

```
tinydb.putString("userName", "john");
String currentUser = tinydb.getString("userName");
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

There is 3 way to store you login details .

1. Using [Shared Preference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)
2. [Store Data in a File](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html)
3. Using [Sqlite](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html).

[**This tutorial**](http://www.skill-guru.com/blog/2011/01/17/data-storage-mechanisms-in-android/) will give you the ideas for storing login details.

Answer (score 0):

You should store data in SharedPreferences rather than global variables because when app crashes, the data updated in static global variables at different times is lost and the default data in it remains.